# how to open encfs folders in 13.04 now that cryptkeeper no longer works

Tags: 13.04, encfs

I've encrypted a folder using cryptkeeper to store important stuff. After installing 13.04 cryptkeeper no longer works. How can I open my encrypted folder? I have tried Gnome Encfs, but I can't seem to open the existing folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not that Cryptkeeper doesn't work under 13.04, it's that 13.04 has eliminated the ability to white-list programs to allow them to place application indicators on the system tray. Cryptkeeper relies on using an indicator in the system tray to tell you it's running and allow you to open and close encfs files.

You can restore your Cryptkeeper functionality by following the directions given here:

http://linuxg.net/how-to-restore-the-systray-whitelist-on-ubuntu-13-04/

I have just upgraded my laptop and desktop to 13.04 and after doing the above, Cryptkeeper works just fine on both units.

Comment: Excellent! Just for people that don't know how to then activate the cryptkeeper icon, follow the link that Doug gives, and then, in terminal, put: 
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'cryptkeeper']"

Log out, log in, and cryptkeeper up and running just like in Ubuntu 12.04/12.10!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to try is Gnome Encfs Manager which can be downloaded by typing the following in terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gencfsm
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-encfs-manager
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in a terminal:

```
encfs encripted_folder destination_folder
```

not pretty, but works.

Note: paths must be absolute

Note 2: sorry for my english :)

Comment: thank you! but it creates a folder in the destination folder, but there's a scrambled file and two other folders in there....