# Need an easy tutorial to lock folders

Tags: gnome, encryption

In Ubuntu 13.04, I've Googled a lot to get three solutions:

1. Rename (hidden) files starting with "." but it hides the folder, but people can access them.
2. Cryptkeeper does not work in Ubuntu 13.04. I've installed it, but it does not show up when I click on it.
3. EncFS tutorials are confusing.

Is there any other GUI tool or easy tutorial for EncFS?

Comment: cryptkeeper does work with 13.04. But you need the white list feature. See: http://askubuntu.com/a/307851/15811

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/104542/is-there-a-way-to-password-protect-individual-folders

Comment: Try this.

http://askubuntu.com/q/379429/183530

Answer (score 2):

**First Method:**

You can use ecryptfs-utils

`sudo apt-get install ecryptfs-utils`

After installing, run the commands below to create your encrypted private folder.

`ecryptfs-setup-private`

You’ll be prompted to create a ‘Mount Passphrase’. The first prompt is for your login password. The one you use to login, type that to continue. Next you’ll be prompted to create a Mount Passphrase. This is the one you’ll use to recover your data at a later date.

---

**Another method: Compressing Trick method**

You don't have to use any third-party software, we will just use the archive manager to compress the file or folder and lock it with a password so that you disallow unauthorized users from copying your contents.

Right click on the file(s) or folder(s) and select Compress:

[image]

In the window that will appear, select a compression format (7z, zip, tar, etc.), then click Other Options:

[image]

Enter any password of your choice, check on "Encrypt the file list too", then click Create:

[image]

You have now compressed and password-protected your file/folder. No user can now extract the archive file unless he/she provides the correct password:

[image]

More Advanced Options

If you want to prevent other users from deleting or moving the password-protected archive file you have just created, open the terminal and cd to where it is stored, then run this command:

```
sudo  chattr +i file-name.ext
```

To undo this, enter this command:

```
sudo  chattr -i file-name.ext
```

Answer (score 0):

If your main intension is to not allow any one else to view whats in that folder then you can do it with File Permissions.

```
chmod -R 700 /path/to/dir/name
```

7-You can Read,Write,Execute

0- No group can do anything

0- other users also can do nothing.

your directory will be completely secured with that.

Comment: With 1 remark: if terminal is not the admin the admin CAN view always view it.

Comment: @Rinzwind I agree, No one can stop root.

Comment: yes or i don't have any other user account except mine.So anybody using my pc will login as admin.

Comment: If you don't have any other users then other people will log as guests and this protection pretty good